# Split string of expression

Tags: python

I want to split string like

```
Expression = "((((324+17)*3)/((936-51)+124))-((13*(72-41))+6))"
```

I use str.split() but it split the number like: "3 2 4 + 1 7"

output:

```
"( ( ( ( 324 + 17 ) * 3 ) / ( ( 936 - 51 ) + 124 ) ) - ( ( 13 * ( 72 - 41 ) ) + 6 ) )"
```

Comment: Can you show what output you are hoping to achieve?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include **the desired behavior**, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [MCVE].

Answer (score 2):

I think what you nee is  to insert space in between every non numeric characters. Split wont be able to do the that job for you and you could use re.sub for the same.

This is what I could come up quickly and there could be better expression to do this in single iteration but it will give you a idea

```
import re
Expression = "((((324+17)*3)/((936-51)+124))-((13*(72-41))+6))"
# Insert space after every non numeric characters
str = re.sub("([^0-9])", r'\1 ', Expression).strip()
#Insert space after numeric characters which are followed by non numeric characters
str = re.sub("([0-9])([^0-9])", r'\1 \2', str).strip()
print(str)
```

**Output**
    `( ( ( ( 324 + 17 ) * 3 ) / ( ( 936 - 51 ) + 124 ) ) - ( ( 13 * ( 72 - 41 ) ) + 6 ) )`

Comment: I think that you figured out their intent.

Comment: If you're using regex, you can make it really simple: `' '.join(re.findall(r'\d+|.', Expression))`

Answer (score 0):

You could use a dictionary to replace certain characters by their padded equivalents:

```
>>> Expression = "((((324+17)*3)/((936-51)+124))-((13*(72-41))+6))"
>>> d = {'(':'( ', ')':' )', '+': ' + ', '-': ' - ', '*': ' * ', '/': ' / '}
>>> ''.join(d[c] if c in d else c for c in Expression)
'( ( ( ( 324 + 17 ) * 3 ) / ( ( 936 - 51 ) + 124 ) ) - ( ( 13 * ( 72 - 41 ) ) + 6 ) )'
```

Note that the padding dictionary pads `(` with one space to the right, `)` with one space to the left, and the operators by spacing on both sides. This prevents over-padding with nested parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking to [tokenize](https://docs.python.org/2/library/tokenize.html) the string. For a Python expression you could do it using the tokenize module, or for a plainer form you could use various search functions. Here are two examples:

```
>>> expression = "((((324+17)*3)/((936-51)+124))-((13*(72-41))+6))"

>>> import re
>>> re.findall('[0-9]+|.', expression)
['(', '(', '(', '(', '324', '+', '17', ')', '*', '3', ')', '/', '(', '(', '936', '-', '51', ')', '+', '124', ')', ')', '-', '(', '(', '13', '*', '(', '72', '-', '41', ')', ')', '+', '6', ')', ')']

>>> import tokenize
>>> [t.string for t in tokenize.tokenize(iter([expression.encode('utf-8')]).__next__)
...  if t.type not in (tokenize.ENCODING, tokenize.ENDMARKER)]
['(', '(', '(', '(', '324', '+', '17', ')', '*', '3', ')', '/', '(', '(', '936', '-', '51', ')', '+', '124', ')', ')', '-', '(', '(', '13', '*', '(', '72', '-', '41', ')', ')', '+', '6', ')', ')']
```

The `iter([bytes]).__next__` part is required because tokenize normally reads out of files, and has no shortcut for a single string.